# Nginx FastCGI cache is EXPIRED when it should not

Tags: nginx, cache, fastcgi, expired

Nginx sets the x-fastcgi-cache header to EXPIRED a few hours after the page was first cached, whereas the cache validity is 1 week.

Nginx Config:

```
fastcgi_cache_path /usr/share/nginx/fastcgi_cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=phpcache:500m max_size=30g inactive=1w use_temp_path=off;
fastcgi_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";
fastcgi_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires Set-Cookie;
fastcgi_cache_valid 1w;

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

...

    set $skip_cache 0;
    set $bypass_reason "NONE";
    set $woocommerce "OK";
 
    # POST requests and URLs with a query string should always go to PHP
    if ($request_method = POST) {
        set $skip_cache 0;
        set $bypass_reason "REQUEST_METHOD";
    }
    
    if ($request_uri ~* ("/wp-admin.*|/cart.*|/panier.*|/commander.*|/checkout.*|/account.*|/myaccount.*|/addond.*|/store.*|/shop.*|/xmlrpc.php|/wp-(app|cron|login|register|mail).php|wp-.*.php|/feed/|index.php|wp-comments-popup.php|wp-links-opml.php|wp-ocations.php|sitemap(_index)?.xml|a-z0-9_-]+-sitemap([0-9]+)?.xml)") { 
        set $skip_cache 1;
        set $bypass_reason "REQUEST_URI_1";
    }
 
    if ( $cookie_yith_ywraq_items_in_raq != "0" ) {
        set $woocommerce "NOK";
    }
    if ( $cookie_yith_ywraq_items_in_raq = "" ) {
        set $woocommerce "OK";
    }
    if ( $woocommerce = "NOK" ) {
        set $skip_cache 1;
        set $bypass_reason "WOOCOMMERCE";
    }

    if ($request_uri ~* "/wp-admin/|/xmlrpc.php|wp-.*.php|/feed/|index.php|sitemap(_index)?.xml") {
        set $skip_cache 1;
        set $bypass_reason "REQUEST_URI_2";
    }   
 
    if ($http_cookie ~* "comment_author|wordpress_[a-f0-9]+|wp-postpass|wordpress_no_cache|wordpress_logged_in|panier|commander") {
        set $skip_cache 1;
        set $bypass_reason "HTTP_COOKIE";
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_cache_bypass $skip_cache;
        fastcgi_no_cache $skip_cache;
        fastcgi_cache phpcache;
        fastcgi_cache_valid 200 301 302 60m;
        fastcgi_cache_use_stale error timeout updating invalid_header http_500 http_503;
        fastcgi_cache_min_uses 1;
        fastcgi_cache_lock on;
        add_header X-FastCGI-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
        add_header X-FastCGI-Cache-Bypass-Reason $bypass_reason;

        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
...
```

I don't understand why even with `inactive=1w` and `fastcgi_cache_valid 1w` I have an expired cache status.

Any ideas on what I am missing here?

Thanks

Comment: I may be mistaken, but it looks like you are setting the default expiration time to 1 week, but then setting it again to only 60 minutes for all php requests using cache: phpcache.

You may be trying to enforce some other expiration with this second line set at 60m, but I believe that may be the source of your issue.

Comment: @Csnap, you're right! I needed the `fastcgi_cache_valid` in the `location ~ \.php$` block at some point but it is useless now. It probably is the source of the issue. I think you may post your comment as an answer. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0):

I may be mistaken, but it looks like you are setting the default expiration time to 1 week, but then setting it again to only 60 minutes for all php requests using cache: phpcache.

You may be trying to enforce some other expiration with this second line set at 60m, but I believe that may be the source of your issue.